# MySQL return different string based on values in table columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have the following function that I created for pulling a user's preferred name:

```
public function getPreferredName($unique_id) {

    $sql = "SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as name FROM `{$this->table}` WHERE `unique_id` = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$unique_id]);

    if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) return null;

    $preferredName = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    return $preferredName;

}
```

This table is a "users" table made up of individuals and companies.

There are some additional fields that I would like to consider in this query:

- "display_as" (individual or company)
- "company_name" (used when display_as = company)

Now i'd like to modify the method above to return either the first and last name OR the company name based on whether the value of the "display_as" column equals "individual" or "company".

If "display_as" equals "individual" return the first_name and last_name fields.

If "display_as" equals "company" return the company_name field.

How can I modify the method above to return either the first_name and last_name together or the company_name value based on the "display_as" column?

Thanks for the help. Cheers

Comment: you need to do that logic outside the query, so add `display_as` and the other fields and check the data returned

Comment: gotcha thank u for the input

Comment: Couple of notes - since you're using `fetchColumn` now, you don't need the `as name` alias. `fetchColumn` will just grab the first column regardless of name. And if `unique_id` is really unique, `LIMIT 1` is redundant. (Neither of those are really problems, just extra code you don't need.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic good points, thank you for the input! I'm having an issue though where the preferred name is not returned for individuals if they do not have a last_name value. Do you know how to fix this by chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the MySQL [IF function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) for this:

```
$sql = "Select If(`display_as` = 'individual',
        CONCAT(IFNULL(first_name,''), ' ', IFNULL(last_name,''))
       ,`company_name`) as name FROM `{$this->table}` WHERE `unique_id` = ? LIMIT 1";
```

This works because you have only two options, individual or company.
If you have more options you will have to use [`case when`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) construct.

Comment: actually @nbk this is not returning anything for display_as = individual when the user does not have a last_name? it seems

Comment: Yes. I added IFNULL, if it encounters a NULL Value the statement uses an empty string instead.

Comment: you can of course use instead of IFNULL  CONCAT_WS see her https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws